# Find element in Map by it's property value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a Map of objects:

```js
const myMap = new Map() 

myMap.set(123, {
  name: 'Lorem',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#1', 'book#2', 'book#3']
  }
})

myMap.set(521, {
  name: 'Ipsum',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#42', 'book#13', 'book#42']
 }
})
```

And at some point, I will need to find an element in Map, which contain `book#42` in `elements.books` array. How Can I do it properly?

Comment: there's a `find` function in es6 that gets you first match from an array. O(n)

Comment: in your case the array would be list of values from Map.

Comment: @Abhilash but Map is not an array, so I can't use myMap.find()

Comment: you can get the array with map.values(). refer answer from @Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the `Map()` with the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement. This statement exposes each entry, which is a *key-value* pair. The value is where you should check for your book. Specifically in the `elements.books` array. When you found your book, return the `key` of the entry. Now you have the key to select the correct entry from the `Map()`.

```js
const myMap = new Map()

myMap.set(123, {
  name: 'Lorem',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#1', 'book#2', 'book#3']
  }
});

myMap.set(521, {
  name: 'Ipsum',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#42', 'book#13', 'book#42']
  }
});

const findKeyOfBook = (book, map) => {
  let result = null;
  for (const [key, value] of map) {
    if (value.elements.books.includes(book)) {
      result = key;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const key = findKeyOfBook('book#42', myMap);
const entryWithBook = myMap.get(key);
console.log(entryWithBook);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the iterator returned by `Map.prototype.values()` into an actual array (with the spread (`...`) syntax or `Array.from()`) and then use `Array.prototype.find()`

```js
const myMap = new Map()

myMap.set(123, {
  name: 'Lorem',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#1', 'book#2', 'book#3']
  }
})

myMap.set(521, {
  name: 'Ipsum',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#42', 'book#13', 'book#42']
  }
})

const findWithSpread = function(map, book) {
  return [...map.values()].find(entry => entry.elements.books.includes(book));
  //return Array.from(map.values()).find(...);
}

const element = findWithSpread(myMap, "book#42");
console.log(element);
```

Comment: This answer helps me too much, easy and fast as I can see. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do simply by doing this using `entries`:

```js
const myMap = new Map() 

myMap.set(123, {
  name: 'Lorem',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#1', 'book#2', 'book#3']
  }
})

myMap.set(521, {
  name: 'Ipsum',
  elements: {
    books: ['book#42', 'book#13', 'book#42']
 }
})

for([key,value] of myMap.entries()){
  if(value.elements.books.includes('book#42')){
    console.log("Found value",key,value)
  }
}
```